# How I can calling a function at specific time in tornado

Tags: python, tornado

How can I call function at specific data/time in tornado?
I've try to use the function `call_at` from tornado library, but does't work as I expected.

```
def call_at(self, when, callback, *args, **kwargs)
```

The documentation say that is necessary to subclass `ioloop` class, and override the function, but I don't understand how to do it properly and I think that this might be out of my scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to subclass anything. You just have to call `ioloop.IOLoop.current()` to get the currently running ioloop instance and then call `call_at` to run your function.

It is, however, easier to use `call_later` instead of `call_at`.

Example using `call_later`:

```
ioloop.IOLoop.current().call_later(delay=10, callback=your_function)

# Tornado will run `your_function` after 10 seconds.
```

If you still want to use `call_at`, here's an example:

```
current_time = ioloop.IOLoop.current().time()
call_time = current_time + 10
ioloop.IOLoop.current().call_at(when=call_time, callback=your_function)

# Tornado will run `your_function` after 10 seconds
```

---

**UPDATE:**

To run a function at a specific time, you can do this:

```
from datetime import datetime

# take note of the current time
now = datetime.now()

# create a datetime object of when you want to call your function
call_time = datetime(year=2018, month=7, day=18, hour=14, minute=30) 

# find the time difference in seconds between `call_time` and `now`
call_time_seconds = (call_time - now).seconds

ioloop.IOLoop.current().call_later(delay=call_time_seconds, callback=your_function)
# Tornado will run your function at 14:30 on 18 July.
```

Comment: tnx, now i've a problem with variable call_time.
I want to call my function at 14:30 of every day, but the time aspected is convertion of data/time in integer: example: 1

531736291.360915

there is a mode to call the function call_at specific time?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a [PeriodicCallback](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html)

class tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback(callback, callback_time, io_loop=None)

Comment: `PeriodicCallback` should be used when you want to run something again and again, periodically. From the question, it seems that OP wants to call a function only once. In that case, `call_at` or `call_later` seems to be a better choice.

Comment: I need to call my function every day at the same time but in specific time: example: 14:30:00